# How to display layer name to GetLegendGraphic request WMS service?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, getlegendgraphic

I have a Mapping and WMS Service that I have published via ArcServer 10.3.1.

When communicating with the WMS service via a web browser, using a [GetLegendGraphic Request](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/communicating-with-a-wms-service-in-a-web-browser.htm). I am returned a graphic of my legend, such as:

[image]

In addition to this, I need the layer name at the top of the legend. Similar to what I see in my MXD:

[image]

Is there any way to get the layer name displayed when I use the [GetLegendGraphic request](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/communicating-with-a-wms-service-in-a-web-browser.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to create your own legend graphic image using software of your choice and saving this to your web server.  Then you need to create a custom (external) GetCapabilities response for your WMS service and substitute the default attributes of the Style section for your `Cumulative Water (bbls)` layer like below:

```
<Style>
     <Name>default</Name>
     <Title>1</Title>
     <LegendURL 
        width="[your image width]" 
        height="[your image height]">
     <Format>[your image format one of image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif]</Format>
     <OnlineResource 
        xlink:href="[URL of your image"] 
        xlink:type="simple"/>
     </LegendURL>
</Style>
```

For details on creating a custom GetCapabilities response see:

[ArcGIS Help 10.1 ~ Using external capabilities files with WMS services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002rt000000)